# Importing theano - nvcc : fatal error : nvcc cannot find a supported version of Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: python, cuda, theano

I got this warning/error message whenever I try importing theano-based packages for the first time (it disappear the second time...). I'm wondering how to get rid of it or disable it since it seems not to affect anything except for being ugly... Thanks in advance for your help!

I have Visual Studio 2010 and C++ installed and added the path of cl.exe into the system path. Below is the original error message:

===============================

> nvcc : fatal error : nvcc cannot find a supported version of Microsoft
>   Visual Studio. Only the versions 2008, 2010, and 2012 are supported
>   ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): Failed to compile cuda_ndarray.cu: ('nvcc
>   return status', -1, 'for cmd', 'nvcc -shared -O3 -Xlinker /DEBUG -D
>   HAVE_ROUND -m64 -Xcompiler
>   -DCUDA_NDARRAY_CUH=47047b939bf764f5977458e316cf235a,-DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION,/Zi,/MD
>   -IC:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\sandbox\cuda -IC:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Anaconda\include -IC:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\gof -o C:\Users\YDuan\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64\cuda_ndarray\cuda_ndarray.pyd
>   mod.cu -LC:\Anaconda\libs -LC:\Anaconda -lpython27 -lcublas
>   -lcudart') ERROR:theano.sandbox.cuda:Failed to compile cuda_ndarray.cu: ('nvcc return status', -1, 'for cmd', 'nvcc -shared
>   -O3 -Xlinker /DEBUG -D HAVE_ROUND -m64 -Xcompiler -DCUDA_NDARRAY_CUH=47047b939bf764f5977458e316cf235a,-DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION,/Zi,/MD
>   -IC:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\sandbox\cuda -IC:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Anaconda\include -IC:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\gof -o C:\Users\YDuan\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64\cuda_ndarray\cuda_ndarray.pyd
>   mod.cu -LC:\Anaconda\libs -LC:\Anaconda -lpython27 -lcublas
>   -lcudart')
>
> ['nvcc', '-shared', '-O3', '-Xlinker', '/DEBUG', '-D HAVE_ROUND',
>   '-m64', '-Xcompiler',
>   '-DCUDA_NDARRAY_CUH=47047b939bf764f5977458e316cf235a,-DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION,/Zi,/MD',
>   '-IC:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\sandbox\cuda',
>   '-IC:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include',
>   '-IC:\Anaconda\include',
>   '-IC:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\gof', '-o',
>   'C:\Users\YDuan\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64\cuda_ndarray\cuda_ndarray.pyd', 'mod.cu', '-LC:\Anaconda\libs', '-LC:\Anaconda', '-lpython27',
>   '-lcublas', '-lcudart']

Comment: Have you followed all the instructions in the `Visual Studio and CUDA` section of the Windows installation documentation? http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html

Comment: Thanks @DanielRenshaw, yes I did follow the very detailed Windows documentation, it worked without error message and warnings. But the next day (probably after I restarted the laptop) the error message started to pop up... Just wondering if anyone has similar experience? I'm afraid of making any changes or reinstall everything at this moment since everything seems to work just fine except for this warning...

Comment: The warning may indicate it is failing to use the GPU. It could be falling back to running in the CPU only.

Comment: Thanks! I decided to just leave it there...

Comment: Which CUDA version are you using?  Which exact version of Visual Studio 2010 are you using?  Professional?  Express?  What is the bitness of your operating system?  32-bit?  64-bit?

Comment: Hi @RobertCrovella, CUDA version seems to be v5.5, I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Express, and OS 64-bit. Thanks for your help

Comment: Running nvcc and the cl.exe compiler from the command line can be tricky, and attempting to do a 64-bit build using a VS 2010 Express install (which does not support 64-bit) is even trickier.  Yes, you would need something like the Windows SDK (did you install that?) but you also need to have various system paths set up properly (don't know if you did that) and you also need a `-ccbin` switch in your compile command, which specifies the path to the the *64-bit* cl.exe compiler installed by the Win SDK 7.1  I don't see that switch in your compile command.

Comment: You might want to figure out how to build a cuda code from the command line first using your config (you will have to experiment with various $PATH$ settings) before you tackle this.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 Express only includes a 32-bit compiler; if you want a 64-bit compiler you would want to download [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279).